# Logits from Multi-Input Model arch. to single Tensorflow sigmoid from entropy loss function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-layers, tensorflow1.15

I have implemented the vast majority of a multi-input model, and I am struggling in the last few steps of defining a **single loss function for 2 incoming logit tensors**.

Lets say I have the following:

```py
logits_cnn =  tf.layers.dense(input1) # shape is [batch_size, num_classes] (e.g. [64,1])
logits_lstm = tf.layers.dense(input2) # shape is [batch_size, num_classes] (e.g. [64,1])
```

Then I want to feed them to the [following](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sigmoid_cross_entropy) loss function:

```
tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels, logits, ...)
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
logits_concat = tf.concat(values = [logits_cnn, logits_lstm], axis= -1, name='concat_logits')
loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels= y, logits = logits_concat)
```

Does the loss implementation make sense? I feel that this is not a conceptually correct approach. As an example, if `y` is shape `[64,1]` and `logits_concat` is shape `[64,2]` , then I'm suggesting that there's 2 classes in play and that's not my intent.

Comment: tf.concat(values = [logits_cnn, logits_lstm], axis= -1)  ,will have shape = (64,2) not(128,1)

Comment: @TouYou , great catch. I did a quick check, and you're absolutely right on the dimensions. I will update my question's commentary.

my question still stands in general with correct documentation.

Comment: to get one logit just add another layer (sigmoid ,softmax.. )before loss ops , and use the two logits you have as input (=features)